# Update IMPORTRANGE function from list of URLs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that lists several URLs of other spreadsheets, all containing client data. This list is constantly being added to as new client sheets are created. I need to be able to aggregate all the client sheet data into one sheet automatically.

I have tried including the importrange text (without making it a formula) for each spreadsheet URL, and then doing `={'URL List'!A2:A},` but all that does is bring in the literal text of the formula.

I'm sure I need to use Google App Script to make this happen, possibly with a loop, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: What do you have so far? It is possible if: 1.) sheet are is same folder 2.) Sheetname is the same or there is always one sheet / first sheet 3.) range is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working:

1. Tools -> Script editor
2. Clear the little myFunction code you see and paste the code from below
3. Change some id's/sheetnames/ranges
4. Save and close
5. Tools -> Macro's -> Import -> Select: 'setImportRange'
6. Tools -> Macro's -> Manage -> Set shortcut

Now whenever you run via the menu -> Macro's or via the shortcut the formula will be updatet with all the sheets in that drive folder.

EDIT: If your sheetname has a space then you must surround with single quotes: "Data!A2:B"  ---> "'Data sheet'!A2:B"

Code:

```
function setImportRange(){
  // Change id of drive folder
  const spreadsheets = DriveApp.getFolderById('1AxxxxxxxxxwxzZv825s-4m8LcnM3u3hm').getFiles();
  const importranges = [];

  while (spreadsheets.hasNext()){
    const ss = spreadsheets.next();
    //Change sheetname and range
    importranges.push(`IMPORTRANGE("${ss.getId()}", "Data!A2:B")`)
  }

//Change master sheetname and the cell where you want the formula.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master').getRange('A1').setFormula(`=QUERY({${importranges.join(';')}},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",0)`)

}
```

EDIT: from list:

```
function setImportRangeFromList(){
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const inputSheet = sss.getSheetByName('List');
  // 2 = start row | 1 = Start column
  const spreadsheets = [].concat(...inputSheet.getRange(2,1,inputSheet.getLastRow()).getValues());
  const importranges = [];

  spreadsheets.forEach(ss => {
    //Change sheetname and range
    importranges.push(`IMPORTRANGE("${ss}", "Data!A2:B")`)
  });

  sss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange('A1').setFormula(`=QUERY({${importranges.join(';')}},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT N",0)`)

}
```

Comment: One thing to add to this solution (which worked wonderfully!) is that if the sheet you're trying to import hasn't been imported previously, and the permissions are any stricter than anyone with the link can edit, then you will need to run an import range of just that sheet and grant access, before the above solution will work.